# Spring batch - stop job running in different JRE

Tags: spring, spring-batch

### Background:

I created a Stop Job which finds running jobs with the specified name as this:

```
jobExplorer.findRunningJobExecutions("job_A")
```

and then, for each execution of job_A it calls:

```
jobOperator.stop(execution.getId());
```

### Issue

when i call the above `stop()` method; even though it eventually accomplishes what i want, but it still throws an exception:

```
    WARN o.s.b.c.l.s.SimpleJobOperator [main] Cannot find Job object
org.springframework.batch.core.launch.NoSuchJobException: No job configuration with the name [job_A] was registered
    at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.support.MapJobRegistry.getJob(MapJobRegistry.java:66) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobOperator.stop(SimpleJobOperator.java:403) [spring-batch-core-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
```

### The Cause

This happens when the `stop()` method tries to located job_A in the    `JobRegistry`.

So even though job_A was found in the "`JobRepository`" because the repository looks in the database, it was not found in the "`JobRegistry`" which is a local cache of job beans created within its runtime environment, since job_A is running withing a different runtime instance it was not registered and threw and error.

### Concern

Even though job 'A' stops i am still concerned what i have missed because of the exception.

I have searched this issue and found only general answers on how to stop a job, however i did not find anyone explaining how to stop a running job of another runtime.

Any answers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `JobOperator` isn't intended to orchestrate distributed batch environments like you're attempting to do.  You really have two options:

1. **Use the `JobRepository` directly -** The part that causes the job to stop successfully in the remote JVM is that the `JobRepository` is updated and the running job in the other JVM knows to check that periodically.  Instead of using the `JobOperator` to accomplish this, just use the `JobRepository` directly to make the update.
2. **Use a more robust orchestration tool like Spring Cloud Data Flow -** This kind of orchestration (deploying, starting, stopping, etc) for jobs (via Spring Cloud Task) is what Spring Cloud Data Flow is for.

You can read more about Spring Cloud Data Flow at the website: https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/

Comment: Thans @Michael Minella for your quick answer. I tried using the `JobRepository` but there is no method for stopping a job. When i tried calling the stop method on the `JobExecution` directly it didnt do anything. it seems that it only sets the `Jobxecution` locally in java but not in the database.

Comment: You need to call `stop` on the `JobExecution`...then pass it to the `JobRepository` for an update.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what Michael mentioned you can solve this by adding some interface to the application allowing you to pass commands to start or stop your job. Something like a webservice. Exposing an end-point to stop it. Now the catch in this case is handling in clustered system may be a bit tricky.